# How to duplicate records in dataframe by including values from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

df1:

```
Index Product     ID     Name
0     Cash        1234   Sam
1     Transfer    5678   Bill
2     Post        9101   Carry
```

df2:

```
Index Time
0      0
1      13
2      14
3      92
4      184
5      365
6      1096
7      1826
```

Expected Output:

```
Index Product     ID     Name Time
0     Cash        1234   Sam   0
1     Cash        1234   Sam   13
2     Cash        1234   Sam   14
3     Cash        1234   Sam   92
4     Cash        1234   Sam   184
5     Cash        1234   Sam   365
6     Cash        1234   Sam   1096
7     Cash        1234   Sam   1826
8     Transfer    5678   Bill  0
9     Transfer    5678   Bill  13
10    Transfer    5678   Bill  14
11    Transfer    5678   Bill  92
12    Transfer    5678   Bill  184
13    Transfer    5678   Bill  365
14    Transfer    5678   Bill  1096
15    Transfer    5678   Bill  1826
16    Post        9101   Carry 0
17    Post        9101   Carry 13
18    Post        9101   Carry 14
19    Post        9101   Carry 92
20    Post        9101   Carry 184
21    Post        9101   Carry 365
22    Post        9101   Carry 1096
23    Post        9101   Carry 1826
```

How to combine df1 and df2 into one dataframe(Expected output), where the Time column of df2 is replicated for each of the records in df1. Appreciate your help in this!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with `merge` with `cross`

```
out = df1.merge(df2,how='cross')
```